# Stream raspi video to php application

Tags: python, camera, streaming-video, php, web-interface

I have an PHP Application running on a "server" and my raspberry which is connected to a display is showing this application (chromium).
Also on my raspberry is the new hd camera connected and I would like to show this camera stream on my php application. I tried with rtsp but the video is extremly slowly...

Any other ideas how I can integrate the camera video on the application without latency?
Or are there any other solutions with python?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/115889/best-way-to-stream-usb-camera-video-in-2020/115972#115972

Comment: @aklingam No, the rpi has no internet connection :(